# how to set type for hexadecimal and convert from hex to string in wso2

Tags: wso2, hex

i have source code like this

```
<api context="/EtheriumTransaction" name="EtheriumTransaction" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="payload"/>
            </log>
            <!-- 
            <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($.id)" name="idusr"/>
            </log>
             -->
             <!-- Get Value of Json -->
            <property expression="json-eval($.id)" name="idusr" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.type)" name="types" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.from_address)" name="address_from" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.to_address)" name="address_to" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.amount)" name="amount" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
           <!-- Convert Amount will send and fee become hex  -->
            <script language="js">
            var log = mc.getServiceLog();
            var amountString = mc.getProperty("amount");
            var amountFloat = parseFloat(amountString);
            var feeString   = "0.1";
            var feeFloat = parseFloat(feeString);
            var newAmount = amountFloat - feeFloat;
            log.info("New Amount : " + newAmount );
            var feeHex = ("0x" + feeFloat.toString(16));
            var newAmountHex = ("0x"+ newAmount.toString(16));
            log.info("New AmountHex : " + newAmountHex  + "feeHex" + feeHex );
            mc.setProperty("newAmountHexs", newAmountHex);
            </script>
            <log>
            <property name="newAmount_hex" scope="default" type="String" expression="$ctx:newAmountHexs" />
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

from the scripts i can get value of hexadecimal. but when i want to log using wso2 property i cannot get my hexadecimal value.. i have try using type="STRING" i cannot get the value. my question is how to get value of hexadecimal in wso2 ?

after i check the problem is wso2 cannot add property for hexadecimal.. so i need to convert my
var newAmountHex = ("0x"+ newAmount.toString(16)); become string value

i have use this

var newAmountHexString = hex_to_ascii(newAmountHex);
function hex_to_ascii(str1)
{
var hex  = str1.toString();
var str = '';
for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
}
return str;
}

but i got error in  for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) cannot use < in script on wso2
here my log

```
[2020-09-03 04:11:16,006] [EI-Core]  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext New Amount : 9.9
[2020-09-03 04:11:16,008] [EI-Core]  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext New AmountHex : 0x9.e666666666668feeHex0x0.1999999999999a
[2020-09-03 04:11:16,009] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: /EtheriumTransaction, MessageID: urn:uuid:ccc5bd5d-99d4-4d82-9ae3-87252d5c2af8, Direction: request, newAmount_hex =
```

Answer (score 0):

wso2 sometimes behaves weird, but to get your value in property, you need add **.toString()** at the end of value, that you are setting as property.

```
mc.setProperty("newAmountHexs", newAmountHex.toString());
```

That works for me :)

Comment: And one more thing. For converting float to hex, you can use:

var newAmountHex = **java.lang.Float.toHexString(newAmount)**